# Conditional processing in proc sql(SAS) using a macro variable

Tags: sql, sas

I need to select the name of states that do not start with M if the the macro variable M=N but return only the names of states that start with M if macro variable is equal to any other variable using conditional processing.
for example:

```
%let M=N;
proc sql;
select states,profit,
case
   when  .....
   else
   end
from geography_dim 
quit;
```

Comment: Is `N` the name of a variable or a value you want to test for?  What do you mean by other variable in  "... if macro variable is equal to any other variable ..."

Comment: For example, if %let M=N then the output should not include state names that start with letter "M" but if %let M= Y or any other letter then the output should include only state names that start with letter M.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of argument, suppose you change the name of the macro variable `M` to something more ridiculously expressive, such as `YN_OPTION_SELECT_M_STATES`

```
%let YN_OPTION_SELECT_M_STATES = N;

proc sql;
select states,profit,
case
   when  .....
   else
   end
from geography_dim

/* add this */
where 
  ("&YN_OPTION_SELECT_M_STATES" eq 'N' & STATE not like 'M%')
  or
  ("&YN_OPTION_SELECT_M_STATES" ne 'N' & STATE     like 'M%')

;
quit;
```

Revert to macro variable `M` if you must, however the code will be somewhat opaque.

Answer (score 1):

It is not SQL but very simple in datastep. If you want check the staring with M macro values in that case "N" you can do like:

```
    /*test data*/
    data geography_dim ;
    states="Aaaaa";profit=10;output;
    states="Naaaa";profit=10;output;
    run;
    /*set macro variable*/
    %let M=N;
    /*check if you want*/
    %put "&M";
    /*your case in datastep*/
    data test;
     set geography_dim;
     if substr(states,1,1) eq "&M" then profit=profit*10;
     else profit=0;
    run;
    /* results
    states  profit
    Aaaaa   0
    Naaaa   100
    */
```